# VBA to output specific text string based upon contents of a text box

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to take a specific column range (B2:B500), check if the cell contains certain text string combinations and if it contains the combinations output a 'x' into a specific column which is depending on the text string in column B. My VBA isn't populating the 'x' into any columns, and I can't identify why.

```
Sub replace()
    With Worksheets("Dave Edit") 'Change to your worksheet
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 2 To 500
            Select Case .Range("B" & i)
                Case Like "*AR*"
                    .Range("M" & i).Value = "x"
                Case Like "*FA*"
                    .Range("L" & i).Value = "x"
            End Select
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

The code runs without error, but I get no output. Also, if you know how I need to make when column B contains both also populate. However, I can go manually check the VBA later to fix that, the current issue is more important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Select Case` is a little off and it is always better to set the worksheet, just in case the active sheet is not the one you expect:

```
Sub x()
    With Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Change to your worksheet
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 2 To 500
            Select Case True
                Case .Range("B" & i) Like "*AR*"
                    .Range("M" & i).Value = "x"
                Case .Range("B" & i) Like "*FA*"
                    .Range("L" & i).Value = "x"
            End Select
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: That gives me a run-time error '9': Subscript out of range. I changed the worksheet and tried different naming conventions. Any idea why it didn't work?

Comment: Make sure you are using the correct sheet name.  The actual name on the tab not the code name and double check the spelling and make sure there are no spaces that are not accounted for.

Comment: That fixed it but now the x result won't populate. Is it possible it has to do with the 'Like' being removed and now it's looking for an exact match for AR/FA?

Comment: @Noble sorry see edit I put them back

Comment: Does that work for you on your end? Every time I try to use any variation of like I get a compile error: Syntax Error.  This is weird as usually VBA is fairly simple to fix in my experience. I've edited my original post with current VBA (same as yours but maybe you can spot something I am missing.

Comment: That worked! Thank you!!!! I was troubleshooting this for longer than I'd care to admit. Thank you again!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!